# VB Arithmetic Overflow on simple division and multiplication

Tags: vb.net, math

I'm still new at coding apps, and I'm trying to make a battle calculator for a game I play. I have done most of the user input and math, but once reaching a certain point I hit an overflow, even after changing my variable to Int64.

The Faulty line is:

```
    damagedealt1 = dcfleet1hp / darmadahp * armadadmg
```

To put some context, user inputs number of ships and ship type, and the software calculates values out of these inputs. Here are the lines related to this code:

```
        'Fleet 1'
        fleet1hp = fleet1hp + fleet1hpboost
        fleet1dmg = fleet1dmg + fleet1dmgboost
        cfleet1hp = fleet1hp * fleet1count
        cfleet1dmg = fleet1dmg * fleet1count
        'D Fleet 1'
        dfleet1hp = dfleet1hp + dfleet1hpboost
        dfleet1dmg = dfleet1dmg + dfleet1dmgboost
        dcfleet1hp = dfleet1hp * dfleet1count
        dcfleet1dmg = dfleet1dmg * dfleet1count
        'Fleet 2'
        fleet2hp = fleet2hp + fleet2hpboost
        fleet2dmg = fleet2dmg + fleet2dmgboost
        cfleet2hp = fleet2hp * fleet2count
        cfleet2dmg = fleet2dmg * fleet2count
        'D Fleet 2'
        dfleet2hp = dfleet2hp + dfleet2hpboost
        dfleet2dmg = dfleet2dmg + dfleet2dmgboost
        dcfleet2hp = dfleet2hp * dfleet2count
        dcfleet2dmg = dfleet2dmg * dfleet2count

        'Text Fields Assignation'

        tfleet1.Text = fleet1type
        tfleet1count.Text = fleet1count
        tfleet1hp.Text = cfleet1hp
        tfleet1dmg.Text = cfleet1dmg

        tfleet2.Text = fleet2type
        tfleet2count.Text = fleet2count
        tfleet2hpp.Text = cfleet2hp
        tfleet2dmg.Text = cfleet2dmg

        'Armada HP Calculations'

        armadahp = cfleet1hp + cfleet2hp
        armadadmg = cfleet1dmg + cfleet2dmg
        darmadadmg = dcfleet1dmg + dcfleet2dmg
        darmadahp = dcfleet1hp + dcfleet2hp

        'Individual Fleet DMG Calculation'
        'Broken Code Here'
        damagedealt1 = dcfleet1hp / darmadahp * armadadmg
        damagedealt2 = dcfleet2hp / darmadahp * armadadmg
        damagetaken1 = cfleet1hp / armadahp * darmadadmg
        damagetaken2 = cfleet2hp / armadahp * darmadadmg
```

And here are definitions of variables:

```
fleet1hp = A single ship in attacking fleet 1's HP
fleet1dmg = A single ship in attacking  fleet 1's DMG
cfleet1hp = The HP combined of all ships in attacking Fleet 1
cfleet1dmg = The DMG combined of all ships in attacking Fleet 1
(then all the same with a 'd' before variable to denote defending fleets)

armadahp = The total HP of all Fleets of attacker
darmadahp = The total HP of all fleets of defender
damagedealt1 = Would be the total damage taken by a single fleet
```

The idea here is that the damage taken is equal to 
fleet hp divided by all fleets hp times incoming damage

Which is what this line should do:

```
damagedealt1 = dcfleet1hp / darmadahp * armadadmg
```

But this line causes a

> System.OverflowException: 'Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.'

[image]

Comment: What are the value of the variables when the overflow occurs?

Comment: I think -2146233066

Comment: If thats the HResult in the QuickWatch

Comment: For reference here is the full code
https://github.com/DexirianPrime/StarMath-/blob/master/StarMath/Result.vb

Comment: Even if the result is -2146233066 that doesnt make sense with the current math considering given input

Comment: What are the values of the variables directly before your calculation and error occur? Are you sure you're not stuck in a loop somewhere?

Comment: Do you have Option Explicit On? The code from github doesn't build.

Comment: Depends, if you multiply -2146233066 by -2146233066, it will be a very large number.

Comment: No I think that's the handle on the exception, not the actual integer result value.

Comment: Not sure what Explicit is? But id assume no

Comment: At the top of your class, type in 'Option Explicit On'. You're then forced to declare all your variables and any potential type or cast issues can be seen.

Comment: How/where are you setting fleet1hull and fleet1hard ?

Comment: It is likely that `darmadahp` has a value of zero at the time of the exception (dividing by zero results in arithmetic overflow. You can verify that by stepping through your code in the debugger.

Comment: Improved formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments in-line.

```
'As near as I can make out this is how
'you declared your variable
 Dim darmadahp As Int64
 Dim armadadmg As Int64
 Dim dcfleet1hp As Int64
 Dim damagedealt1 As Decimal
 'Always check for division by zero
 If darmadahp * armadadmg <> 0 Then
     'Option Strict (which should always be on) requires the CDec
     damagedealt1 = CDec(dcfleet1hp / (darmadahp * armadadmg))
End If
```

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer. However `damagedealt1 = dcfleet1hp / darmadahp * armadadmg` is equivalent to `damagedealt1 = (dcfleet1hp / darmadahp) * armadadmg` and not `damagedealt1 = dcfleet1hp / )darmadahp * armadadmg)`, so it is only necessary to check that `arardadmg` is not zero. On the other hand, the final two statements in the OP require checking that `armadahp` is not zero.

Comment: @Blackwood Thank you for the correction. I altered my code slightly with parenthesis around the denominator. I hope this is correct. If it is not what the OP intended, he can fix the code as you suggested.

Comment: I suspect that the OP intends `(dcfleet1hp / darmadahp) * armadadmg`, but I agree that we should let the OP decide.